# Correct callback function when JQuery UI tab clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Anybody has an an IDEA why am I not getting alert-'load called'. When clicked on the tabs in the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/newair/Lxy5A/).

```
$(function() {  
var tabControl = $("#tabs");
alert('function called');
tabControl.tabs({ heightStyle: "auto",
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
    },             
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {

    },
    load: function (event, ui) {

    alert('load called');
    }
});
 });
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
activate: function( event, ui ) {
     alert('clicked')
}
```